# Rails 4.1.2 json Arabic support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activesupport

I'm using Rails 4.1.2, along with `gem 'activesupport-json_encoder', github: 'rails/activesupport-json_encoder'` and `gem 'algoliasearch-rails'`. The problem is when i call the `.to_json` on on ActiveRecord object that have Arabic characters, it replaces any Arabic characters with `�`.

```
 > p = Product.find 100
 #<Product id: 93038, name: "Men Jacket , front zipper, double colour light gre...", brand: "\xD8\xA7\xD8\xAE\xD8\xB1\xD9\x8A">
 > puts p.to_json
 {"id":93038,"name":"Men Jacket , front zipper, double colour light grey sizeXL","brand":"��������"}
```

Comment: you can use serializer to override the default to_json, then you can encode the Arabic characters to UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with to_json? Those do look like utf-8 bytes but is p.brand.encoding UTF8?

Comment: @FrederickCheung `p.to_json` will work fine, if you run `p.brand.force_encoding("utf-8")` before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by forcing the "utf-8" encoding, in https://github.com/rails/activesupport-json_encoder/blob/master/lib/active_support/json/encoding/active_support_encoder.rb#L127. I forked the gem here https://github.com/mahmoud-abdelaziz/activesupport-json_encoder .

By adding `gem 'activesupport-json_encoder', github: 'mahmoud-abdelaziz/activesupport-json_encoder'`, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `as_json` method in product model as the following:

```
def as_json(options)
  hash = self.serializable_hash.delete('brand')
  super(hash.merge({brand: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self.brand)})
end
```

Then use the following:

```
p = Product.find 100
puts p.as_json
```